# Bootstrap Collapsed Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having problems with my Bootstrap collapsed navbar, where the items in the menu wont appear on a single line as they should. It may have something to do with my navbar floating right, which I wish to keep as it goes with the design.

Here is the code in question, I have used placeholders for the menu items:

```
<div id="divNav">
                 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
                  <div class="container-fluid">
                    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      </button>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                      <ul class="nav nav-pills navbar-right">
                        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="something.html">something</a></li>
                        <li><a href="something.html">something</a></li>
                        <li><a href="something.html">something</a></li>
                        <li><a href="something.html">something</a></li>
                        <li><a href="something.html">something</a></li>
                        <li><a href="something.html">something</a></li>
                        <li><a href="something.html">something</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
                </nav>
            </div> <!--End of divNav -->
```

And here is a photo of the unexpect behavior once collapsed, is there a way round this?

http://imgur.com/fP6WcOt

Thanks

Comment: what about css you applied ?

Comment: @AlpeshPrajapati I havent added any significant css apart from colours of the background and text

Comment: It's the use of .nav-pills in the navbar. Not supposed to go there but you can add them in another way. See answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.nav-pills`, though their name *sort of* implies (if you are not familiar with Bootstrap) that they work inside the `.navbar`, they don't actually go there, that is not their intended use.

If you want a design pattern like `.nav-pills` in the navbar, you will need to copy (not remove) their styles out of the un-minified bootstrap.css and rename them. Put the float part in a min-width media query and the rest of the styles outside and before the min-width media query.

**DEMO: http://jsbin.com/zoham/1/edit**

**NEW CSS:**

```
.navbar-nav-pills > li > a {
    border-radius: 2px
}
.navbar-nav-pills > li + li {
    margin-left: 2px
}
.navbar-nav-pills > li.active > a,
.navbar-nav-pills > li.active > a:hover,
.navbar-nav-pills > li.active > a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #428bca;
}
@media (min-width:768px) { 
    .navbar-nav-pills > li {
        float: left
    }
}
```

**HTML - change class name :**

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav-pills navbar-right">
```

Comment: Is there anyway I can center the text instead of floating it to the left?

Comment: Center it when it's small or in the large viewport? Or both?

Comment: Just center the collapsed menu items and also when I increase the min width range to 1075, the menu items are all floating right, which I cant understand

Comment: You have the navbar-right on the ul, so they will go right, you put either navbar-right or navbar-left or leave it off and it will default to navbar-left. There is no such option for navbar-center since you have the navbar-brand there. That is another SO question. To center the menu items, per line, in the collapsed menu: http://jsbin.com/zoham/2/edit -- add text-align:center on the > a